Toshiba HDD: How to change logical sector size to 4096 byte?

OS: Debian 12 (Bookworm)
HDD: TOSHIBA MG10AFA22TE (SATA)
Firmware Revision: 0102

I've tried to change logical sector size of multiple HDDs, but it doesn't work:
hdparm --set-sector-size 4096 --please-destroy-my-drive /dev/sdX
changing sector size configuration to 4096: SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 53 e0 01 21 04 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
succeeded

After unplugging and reconnecting the HDD it's still 512 bytes:
hdparm -I /dev/sdX | grep -F Sector
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes [ Supported: 512 4096 ]
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes

Any ideas what's going wrong here? The disk is directly connected to the motherboard.

Is it a SATA or SCSI (SAS) disk, out of curiosity?

@u1686_grawity SATA

hdparm should not be used anymore. It's a tool for setting up PATA IDE drives. Just that many SATA IDE drive support it too, doesn't mean that all SATA drives support it. But you might try to go to your BIOS or SATA controller and check if you find some compatibility mode. I don't recommend enabling these compatibility mode. Just format the drive or a partition with a 4k block sized filesystem and all is fine.

@paladin false information

@TomYan what exactly is a false information? I strongly recommend to not write such useless comments.

@paladin I strongly recommend not to randomly write something like xxx should not be used anymore. Not only that it's disrespectful, it's also hilarious when the particular case you wrote makes no sense, let alone what you wrote in particular is false information / FUD. Besides, it also makes no sense to say something like "xxx hardware supports xxx software". And you don't need IDE compatibility mode for a SATA drive to "support" ATA commands.

I explained why it should not be used anymore. But if you like, keep staying in the world of 1999. PS ATA commands ya, but to be more precise, PATA commands, a compatibility layer of SATA drives to emulate the behavior of a PATA drive

@paladin No one needs your false and useless explanation.

lol, troll someone other

@paladin Please read some ACS command sets spec before you troll (or more like "clown"). In particular, the SET SECTOR CONFIGURATION command was even introduced in ACS-4 (which isn't quite freely available), which is not only published but drafted in 2015, which is in turn 2 years after SATA 3.2 is released.

@paladin To be frank, if you have just a tiny bit more experience or have ever read a tiny bit more, you wouldn't say something as silly as "PATA commands, a compatibility layer of SATA drives to emulate the behavior of a PATA drive". More importantly, It's fine to not know things, but please don't spread FUD when that's your case.

I have the exact same objective and tried this but I get the following error : "Setting sector size not supported on this device" even using "--force" parameter...
After contacting Toshiba support, they gave me access to a tool called "TSBDRV" (I got access to version 13.09c) and I was able to change the logical sector size of my Toshiba MG10F HDDs.
Little tip, when using the tool :

from a Windows machine, use the drive number instead of the volume letter as device parameter
from a Linux machine, use only "sdX" instead of "/dev/sdX" as device parameter


Thanks! Currently they're reacting a little bit odd and won't send me the mentioned file, only strange questions...
